# I can upload .json file in sharepoint site but cant access the file in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, iis

I can upload .json file in SharePoint site, but can't access the file in SharePoint 2010. Is it possible that Microsoft product won't allow to access .json file in SharePoint 2010?

I came across post "The extension is blocked to maintain integrity within the SharePoint product" Is it valid ? I found nothing to validate this point.
If this is true, is there any way to access .json file in SharePoint 2010 by modifying handlers in web.config files?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint's web.config defines a custom handler for JSON files.

```
<handlers>
<add name="JSONHandlerFactory" path="*.json" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
</handlers>
```

In effect, SharePoint has reserved .JSON for its own use and processes them with its own handler.

You could save your files as .TXT and still read them from JavaScript as JSON files.    I.e. MyData.json.txt

Comment: I'm trying to save tsconfig.json to a library. It's not an option renaming the file. I wish SP would be less cumbersome to configure. Have just lost a whole day trying to make it accept such file.